# What is the formula for the period of any trignometric function?

Tags: trigonometry

My question is pretty simple: Does the equation p=2pi/b work for ALL trig ratios? (cos, sin, tan, csc, sec, cot)

I have the following questions, and am trying to find the period for them all. Must I rearrange the formula for each trig ratio, or is the formula work for all of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for everything except $\tan$ and $\cot$. $\tan$ and $\cot$ themselves have period $\pi$, not $2 \pi$, so the period of $\tan(bx)$ is $\frac{\pi}{b}$, not $\frac{2 \pi}{b}$.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. +1 Thank-you!